# MatSort not working. Throws Error: MatSortHeader must be placed within a parent element with the MatSort directive

Tags: angular, angular-material

After i specify the **mat-sort-header** attribute on matHeaderCellDef to create a Sortable table in Angular Material, getting the following error

> MatSortHeader must be placed within a parent element with the MatSort directive.

```
<mat-table #table matSort [dataSource]="myHttpDataSource">
....
<ng-container matColumnDef="myColumnName">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.somedetails}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Any pointers/help appreciated

Comment: Did you import the `MatSortModule` ?

Comment: Yes i added MatSortModule in both app-material.ts as well as in app.module.ts

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Realized that I was using the old mdSort tag in another mat-table which was causing this issue. After changing to matSort the issue got resolved.

Comment: Don't post and accept your own answer after someone solved the issue for you...

Answer (score 44):

Add 'matSort' attribute to mat-table

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: Good catch. I was using `mat-sort` instead of `matSort`

Comment: Thanks! For more reference please go to: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting

Comment: @Yousefkhan , thanks even I commited same mistake and got struck.

Answer (score 9):

```js
<mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

```html
To add sorting behavior to the table, add the matSort directive to the 
table and add mat-sort-header to each column header cell that should 
trigger sorting.
```

Comment: Lol, I just forgot to add "matSort" in mat-table-tag

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 9
}

Answer (score 3):

After following the Angular documentation, I have ended in the same issue described here. The solution is:

- Add the matSort directive to the table and add mat-sort-header to each column header, as described in other questions.
- Import MatSortModule: `import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';` As described on the [API docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api). And remember to  import it on the imports section `imports: [...,  MatSortModule]`
- And assign the sorting property to the datasource in the component of your table.

  ```
   @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort!: MatSort;

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<...>(...);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   }
  ```

Comment: People don't forget to import your MatSortModule unlike me

Answer (score 0):

could you give us more info please?

have you try catch the event?

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote step by step code manually and the problem is the official Angular 13 documentation, the page (https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)
"For example, you can add sorting and pagination to the table by using **MatSort** and MatPaginator and mutating the data provided to the table according to their outputs." This way it causes the error.
And it repeats again in a number of places "The **MatSort** is one provided...".
In my case, the problem is adding "MatSort" instead of "matSort".
In the source code of the example it is different (the 1st line is "<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" **matSort** ".
Thus it is solved with changing  **MatSort** to **matSort**.

The 2nd issue with TypeScript 2.7+ version. Need to change

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

to something like that

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort!: MatSort;
```

Here is the link to discussion
[MatSort not working. Throws Error: MatSortHeader must be placed within a parent element with the MatSort directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019913/matsort-not-working-throws-error-matsortheader-must-be-placed-within-a-parent)